# Redirect /directory to /directory/?

Tags: redirect, directory, dedicated-server, mediatemple

I am using a (dv) server from Media Temple, and I have wordpress installed on the root of my domain.

I have a directory called support that holds a standard xhtml webpage, but if the user enters the domain name as follows:

```
www.domain.com/directory
```

the wordpress page not found shows up, however, if the user enters:

```
www.domain.com/directory/
```

the xhtml page shows up.

Is it possible to force the server to direct anyone who types /directory to /directory/?

Sorry if this isn't making much sense!

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: what type of server? Nginx, IIS, Apache, something creative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Linux server it should happen anyway as you can't have a file and a directory in the same place with the same name - I'd guess that the request is being rewritten so maybe your .htaccess file would help here.

Aside from that, the following in your .htaccess should do it:
`RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^directory$ directory/`
or
`Alias /directory /directory/`

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour you are asking for is the DEFAULT in any sane server for good reasons...

assuming it's apache, maybe your hoster disabled THIS?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash
(it would be a really bad idea to do that globally on a shared hosting server,
 if it's the case, do complain about it...)

also read that entry to understand WHY that behaviour is the default...

Comment: actually, most likely it's due to some rewriterule(s) in your htaccess file for wordpress that overrides the default behaviour...
usually you would have a rule in there that passes requests for existing files to the default handling...